# How to I get this Duravit toilet seat off to tighten the mountings

Tags: toilet

Both the pans in our house have loose seats.  I have tightened one, where the seat/cover lifted off vertically, but the second one is of a different construction:

[image]

Logic would suggest the key is to unscrew the screw, but it won't budge using the arsenal available to me, and it is made really difficult by the lack of clearance above the screw.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Is there nothing underneath? Every toilet seat I've ever fitted (and that's quite a few) have had the fixings on the underside. There may be a nut you can get more purchase on, even if only to loosen it. Or a gentle tap with an impact driver, if you have one.

Comment: @SiHa Doh!  Toilet #1 (the one I was able to fix) has a shroud that wraps the pan and cistern, providing no access to the internals, and I was assuming toilet #2 was the same.  It isn't.  I can reach underneath and feel a very rusty fastener.

Comment: Yes, they're generally too rusty to shift :(

Comment: You're going to have to deal with the rusty fastener...  Can you take a picture underneath there?